# Remove Integration Runtime resources and its dependencies from adf_publish ARM template

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-deployment, azure-devops-extensions

I am deploying to higher environments from adf_publish ARM template through Azure Devops. My requirement is to exclude integrationRuntimes from the ARM template and deploy (because we are creating IRs manually in higher environment). Is there any way to do that?

We do not want to use "Azure Data Factory Deployment" task. I only want to deploy through "ARM template deployment" for obvious reasons like custom Parameterization.

We do not want to manually update the ARM template in adf_publish; want to implement CI/CD way.

I can see conditional deployment in ARM template is an option to exclude the existing resources from deployment but then would have to manually add those conditions in ARM template which we don't want to do.